# Executing SELECT query return false

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a PHP site that I uploaded in 000webhost. It needs a database to store data. But when I try to sign in it didn't sign in. When I check the connection it turns out the connection  was fine. Still not able to access the database. So I wrote a small script to check database access and it failed. I have a table named songs which contains some songs.

Here is the script :

```
<?php
    ob_start();

    session_start();
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'xxxxxxx';
    $pass = 'xxxxxxx';
    $db = 'xxxxxxx';

    $timezone = date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");

    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $pass); 

    if($con)
    {
        echo "Connection success";
        $query  = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM songs");
        if($query){
            $tb = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
            print_r($tb);
        }
        else {
            echo " failed db access";
        }
    }   
    else {
        echo " connection failed";
    }    
?>
```

The details have been kept hidden for security reasons.
The above script gives the following output:

```
Connection success failed db access
```

Comment: try to connect to your database using terminal first and check if the user you  are using to connect to the database has permissions for the database

Comment: how? the database is online hosted at 000webhost

Comment: you can use mysql -h (hostname) -u (username) -p

Comment: where ? the hosting dont have a terminal

Comment: but you have terminal in your system..

Comment: yes but how to get the hostname. there it says local host and localhost will use my own local mysql table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work, because you're using `PDO` for connection and `mysqli` to query. Change your connection to mysqli

```
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

or change your query to PDO

```
$query  = $con->query("SELECT * FROM songs");
```

Comment: I tried that and it worked , I also tried using mysqli_connect. The problem is When I am trying it on my real site it is not able register me succesfull and the page refresh back. I cant get into the website without loging in and it is not registering. P.S - It used to do when I am testing with xampp in my local computer

Comment: just neede to add database name at the end after password like :          $con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $databasename);

Comment: Good. I'm glad you solved your issue. I'll edit the connection string in my answer. I have no idea how I forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

The output you are showing is misleading, `failed db access`. As per below code, database was connected successfully and you were executing query, which didn't executed it seems and flow going to `else` block.

```
if($query){
// your code 
}
else {
   echo " failed db access";
}
```

You need to check,

1. If you are using same user credentials and has access to the table.
2. If same table exists
3. If you have provided correct database details where you have created tables.

**==Updated==**

As I mentioned earlier, user might not have sufficient privilege to access `songs` table. To `GRANT` access, you need to execute following SQL

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '<username>'@'localhost; WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: The table is there and there is data in it. failed to access db is a short message meaning the query didnt executed and if the connection was not successful then it should never have entered the if($con) statement

Comment: @AyanBanerjee and I said same. Query didn't executed, because of above mentioned reason

Comment: I created the table . And I tried to run a query in phpmyadmin and it worked. Beside Can you tellme how to know if I have access to table or not

Comment: @AyanBanerjee are you using same user credentials from php ??

Comment: @AyanBanerjee So, I'm asking are you using same user here or not ? I know, you already mentioned in phpadmin works.

Comment: no and yes I am using the same credential here and also in phpmyadmin. Both worked but I cant access the database from my phpfile

Comment: @AyanBanerjee you need to understand the difference between database and table. It is definitely user privilege, which can't guarantee until I see the env. So, you need to debug from here.I already gave you checklists.

Comment: i Know the difference between database and table. I created the table so I should have user rights. still how to check for it. p.s- i went to phpmyadmin and tested that query and it gave me all the data inside the songs table

Comment: ok so after digging deep I found the problem and it is because my username has no access privilige. so how to add privilige to my username from phpmyadmin

Comment: @AyanBanerjee As I said very beginning, but you keep saying it has access. You need to grant access, I will update my post